# 2016 Chrysler 300 Key Fob only works AFTER touching the vehicle

Tags: keyless-entry, fob, chrysler-300c

2016 Chrysler 300C

Key Fob no longer locks/unlocks/starts, nor unlocks the trunk.  However, the key fob will do all these things only AFTER I physically open and then close the driver side door (I don't need to get into the vehicle).  Once I open the door (and then close it - with the key fob in my possession), the key fob will do all it is supposed to.

Then... after a period of time (a few hours?), the key fob will no longer function; resulting in my having to open and then close the drivers side door to "reset" everything.

What's making this happen!!?  Can this issue be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: First thing you need to do is change the battery in the prox fob.